# python unflatten list based on another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists :

```
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
list_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

list_1 and list 2 are always the same length

I want to format list_2 and unflatten it using list_1 (positions of elements)

desired output :

```
list_2_formatted = [[a,b], [c,d,e]]
```

Comment: You're aware that we normally start counting elements from 0, yes?

Comment: You can do something like: `[[list_2[idx-1] for idx in sub_l] for sub_l in list_1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
list_2_formatted = list_1
for idx1, element in enumerate(list_1):
    for i in range(len(element)):
        list_2_formatted[idx1][i] = list_2.pop(0)

print(list_2_formatted)

Output: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same concept here...

```
list_2_formatted = list_1

list_2_itemNumber=0
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    for j in range(len(list_1[i])):
        list_2_formatted[i][j]=list_2[list_2_itemNumber]
        list_2_itemNumber+=1
print (list_2_formatted)
```